# Why I can't get output from this batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

This program stops automatically! When I enter correct `name` and `password` (i.e it is not executing from 8th line). Please check if I made any mistakes.

```
@echo off
:s
set t=0
set /p a= enter your name
set /p b= enter your password
if %a%==andrew(set /a  t=%t%+1)
if %b%==123 (set /a t=%t%+2 )
if %t%==3 ( echo welcome andrew 
echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
:r
set /p c=want to change your settings -yes -no
if %c%==no (echo ok
goto e
)
if %c%==yes (set /p p= what you want to change -name(1) -password(2)
if %p%==1 (set /p a=enter name to change)
if %p%==2 (set /p a=enter password to change)
)
)
if %t%==2 echo %a% is not authorised
if %t%==1 echo enter correct password
if %t%==0 echo Both name and id are wrong enter again
goto r
goto s 
:e
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of things. Do not set single character variables or label names. rather use `set vara` than using `set a` but making things recognisable like using variables that means something, makes things less confusing.

when matching variables with a value using `==` double quote each side. i.e `if "%var" == "123"`

For selection, use `choice` instead of `set /p`

Also, when using `set /a` the better way to add is `set /a vart+=1` instead of `set /a %vart%+1`

This should do more or less what you want.

```
@echo off
:start
set vart=0
set /p "name=Enter your name: "
set /p "pass=Enter your password: "
if /i "%name%" == "andrew" set /a vart+=1
if "%pass%" == "123" set /a vart+=2
if %vart%  equ 3 echo welcome andrew 
echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
:settings
choice /c YN /m "Change your settings?"
if %errorlevel% equ 0 goto opt0
goto opt%errorlevel%
:opt0
echo You Pressed CTRL+C and selected "N"
exit /b 1
:opt2
pause
goto :eof

:opt1
choice /c UP /m "Change your User or Password?"
if %errorlevel% equ 0 goto opt0
goto chng%errorlevel%

:chng2
set /p "name=Enter name to change: "
goto :eof

:chng1
set /p "pass=Enter password to change: "

if %vart% equ 2 echo %a% is not authorised
if %vart% equ 1 echo enter correct password
if %vart% equ 0 echo Both name and id are wrong enter again
goto settings
goto start
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `@echo on` and you may see something like this when the script is executed:

```
--> set t=0 

--> set /p a= enter your name 
enter your nameandrew

--> set /p b= enter your password 
enter your password123

--> if andrew == andrew(set /a  t=0+1) 

--> if 123 == 123 (set /a t=0+2  ) 
(echo was unexpected at this time.

--> if ==no (echo ok
```

The script stopped with error:

> (echo was unexpected at this time.

Line 7 showed OK:

> ```
> if 123 == 123 (set /a t=0+2  )
> ```

though, next command output seen is:

> ```
> if ==no (echo ok
> ```

which means `%c%` is undefined as you can see a value missing left of the `==` that caused the error.

This could be happening as to the opening parentheses in line 8:

> ```
> if %t%==3 ( echo welcome andrew
> ```

The parser will see the opening parentheses and will keep reading the lines until it reaches a closing parentheses. It will substitute the percentage enclosed variables before execution. This makes `%c%` undefined as `%c%` is not defined before the opening parentheses on line 8 began the read.

So it seems the parser read:

> ```
> if %t%==3 ( echo welcome andrew
> echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> :r
> set /p c=want to change your settings -yes -no
> if %c%==no (echo ok
> goto e
> )
> ```

And does variable substitution of known values of `t=3` and `c=`:

> ```
> if 3==3 ( echo welcome andrew
> echo ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> :r
> set /p c=want to change your settings -yes -no
> if ==no (echo ok
> goto e
> )
> ```

The error of `if ==no (echo ok` is shown.

Your question in the title:

> why i cant get output from this batch script?

It is the opening parentheses in line 8. So one should ask thy self... What is that opening parentheses doing there in line 8 when it will include a label `:r` and a `set /p` that sets a variable `c` that can cause an undefined variable?

If the opening parentheses is meant to be there, view `set /?` that may show an example like:

```
set VAR=before
if "%VAR%" == "before" (
    set VAR=after
    if "%VAR%" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
)
```

The example code and the details in `set /?` informs you how set variables work.

The label between the parentheses would still be a concern as it can cause error in a read block of code.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the syntax of the commands, such as `if` and `set` before posting.
Addressing some problems in your code:
First,

```
if %a%==andrew(set /a  t=%t%+1)
```

is intercepted by cmd.exe as:
if `%a%` is `andrew(set`, run a command called `/a  t=%t%+1`. Also, please double quote all `set /p ...=` in your script, even though it can't handle poison characters.

Second, you have unescaped closing parenthesis `)` in your `if`, which can cause interception errors.